# How to use discord.py to censor bad words

Tags: python, discord.py

Right now, I have the following:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import os
bot = Bot(command_prefix="?")
with open("bad-words.txt") as file: # bad-words.txt contains one phrase per line
    bad_words = [bad_word.strip().lower() for bad_word in file.readlines()]
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message_content = message.content.strip().lower()
    async for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message:
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, "{}, your message has been censored.".format(message.author.mention))
            await bot.delete_message(message)
bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

I have this Python code, and it doesn't work. I'm not sure why because I can't see the errors with my current hosting situation.

The goal is to have the bot delete a message whenever it contains a blacklisted phrase in `bad-words.txt`, which contains one phrase per line.

The bot runs, but doesn't do anything. What am I missing here? Thank you!

Comment: That `async for` should be a regular `for`. Why can't you see the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you probably want to wait for the search to finish, you could just change the `async for` to a regular `for` as mentioned by Patrick Haugh:

```
for bad_word in bad_words:
    if bad_word in message:
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "{}, your message has been censored.".format(message.author.mention))
        await bot.delete_message(message)
```

However, in Python 3, the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) method can be used to simplify this further:

```
if any(bad_word in message for bad_word in bad_words):
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "{}, your message has been censored.".format(message.author.mention))
    await bot.delete_message(message)
```