# How should I make a Discord bot that detects certain words then delete them?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So i've been trying to learn myself Python by making a Discord bot, everything went well until i had this error `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'delete'`. I was going to make a feature in which if it detects certain words from a dictionary, it will be deleted. I've read  [Benjamin Soyka's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460891/how-do-i-make-a-discord-py-bot-filter-certain-words-phrases) asking how to do the same, but with older version of Discord.py

Right now, my code is :

```py
with open("bad_words.txt") as file: # bad-words.txt contains one blacklisted phrase per line
    bad_words = [bad_word.strip().lower() for bad_word in file.readlines()]


@client.event    
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content) #prints messages in console
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message.content:
            print("bad words detected") #prints when bad word is found
            await client.delete(message) #delete said message
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

I've tried with different ways like making classes or nested functions, but seems like none is working for me. Sorry if this question seems silly, and Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (Rewrite version)

```
await message.delete()
```

instead of

```
await client.delete(message)
```

Comment: Whoa, it does work! My knowledge about OOP is still lacking. Thanks!